# Nav Bar issues with slideDown and slideUp

Tags: jquery

I have searched the forum and have not found an issue similar to this.

First of all, example of my code can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/LMWLn/97/

While it is technically working, there are a couple of issues that I would like to clean up:

1. When I move the mouse over "Solutions" or "About Us", the animation works just fine. It slides down and then slides up. However, when I move from "Solutions" straight over to "About Us", (and also vice verse) it makes an immediate change instead of sliding up the first item and then sliding down the second.
2. If I have just looked at the "About Us" content and then let it close, and then mouse over the "Solutions" tab, the content DIV slides down the full height of the previous content and then bounces back up to its own height (I hope that makes sense...)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Velcrobelly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first issue happens because you set dropdownclosetimer = null when you hover over an item. This cancels the call to HideMainDropdown(). The second issue is because '#maindropdown' stretches to fit its content. It was stretched to fit '#aboutus-dropdowncontent' which is larger.

On a side note, your html is not semantic with your sub nav broken out from your main nav. Generally people use a list too. Here is a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/LMWLn/101/  I'm sure the CSS could be done better on it but it works.

Comment: I have looked at something like this before, but my requirements are for the dropdown to span the entire page. Any recommendations on how to do that with your solution?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "span the entire page". Do you mean this: http://jsfiddle.net/LMWLn/102/

Comment: So much closer, thank you. This allowed me to rethink it a bit and this is what I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/LMWLn/104/.

Only issue I see now is that if you move off of a tab and then hit the dropdown as it is moving back up, the dropdown will bounce up and down. Example: mouse over the "About Us" tab and then off of it to the bottom-right and then move down before the dropdown completely disappears.

Comment: Yeah, I think I know what you are talking about. The previous animation isn't being canceled so they stack on top of eachother. Checkout this plugin that allows you to set a delay on the hoverOver/hoverOut events.: http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html